# Implicit and explicit method hiding

Tags: c#, method-hiding

I have the following two use cases:

```
class BaseCalculator
{
    public int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }   
}

class Calculator : BaseCalculator
{
    public new int Sum ( int x , int y )
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

This did explicitly hide the `Sum` method using the `new` keyword.

```
class BaseCalculator
{
    public int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

class Calculator : BaseCalculator
{
    public int Sum ( int x , int y )
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I didn't understand the difference between the two. Does the second code implicitly hide the Sum method?

Comment: Yes, it is implicitly hiding the Sum method of the base class. This is also very bad still (and I think will generate a warning?) - always use new or override in this case. This will make clear what your intention was, and that you didn't just forget it.

Comment: The difference is in your compiler output window, 1 less warning when using `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In C#, derived classes can contain methods with the same name as base class methods. If the method in the derived class is preceded with the **new** keyword, the method is defined as being independent of the method in the base class.

And why the two code pieces are the same is explained below:

> Using the **new** keyword tells the compiler that your definition hides the definition that is contained in the base class. This is the default behavior.

The only difference is that by using `new` keyword, you avoid the compiler warning.

More explanation can also be found on MSDN in [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. There is no semantic difference. The new keyword merely emphasizes the hiding. It is similar to the behavior of the `private` modifier. Members are private by default, but you can write `private` anyway.